# Apache Zeppelin Run All button is disabled

Tags: apache-http-server

The button that runs all paragraphs is greyed out in one of my Zeppelin notes (all other notes have this option working). The documentation tells how to enable/disable the run button for each paragraph (using the paragraph configuration wheel setting) but I can't see any mention of such customization available for the 'run all' button. My site uses Apache Zeppelin version 0.7.3. The notes use the Spark interpreter. Any pointer to re-enable the run all button, much appreciated.

Comment: What I discovered, eventually, was that one of the subsequent paragraphs had failed to finish and was in a hanging state. Cloning and then removing the errant paragraph fixed the problem.